# How can I export the list of Adobe Plug-Ins with their version numbers in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

How can I export the list of Adobe Plug-Ins with their version numbers in Adobe Acrobat?

If I go to `About Adobe Plug-Ins`, there seems to be no way to export the list:

[image]

---

For example, in Eclipse, I can get the list by copy-pasting from `About Eclipse SDK > Eclipse SDK Installation Details`:

[image]

Output:

```
  AnyEditTools  2.6.1.201602151951  AnyEditTools.feature.group  Andrey Loskutov
  C/C++ Development Tools   8.6.0.201502131403  org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group   Eclipse CDT
  Eclipse Color Theme   1.0.0.201410260308  com.github.eclipsecolortheme.feature.feature.group  GitHub
  Eclipse Moonrise UI Theme 0.8.9.201404052318  com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.feature.feature.group  Andrea Guarinoni
  Eclipse SDK   4.5.0.I20150603-2000    org.eclipse.sdk.ide Eclipse.org
  GFM Viewer feature    1.9.3   code.satyagraha.gfm.viewer.feature.feature.group    Satyagraha
  Json Tools    1.1.0   org.sweetlemonade.eclipse.json.feature.feature.group    Sweet Lemonade
  Lua Development Tools 1.3.1.201601191732  org.eclipse.ldt.feature.group   Eclipse LDT
  Lua Development Tools - Remote Development Support    1.4.1.201608302152  org.eclipse.ldt.remote.feature.group    Eclipse LDT
  Marketplace Client    1.4.0.v20150618-1659    org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group   Eclipse Marketplace Client
  Path Tools Feature    1.0.67  PathToolsFeature.feature.group  Sandip V. Chitale
  Path Tools RSE Integration Feature - Optional (Requires RSE)  1.0.64  PathToolsRSEFeature.feature.group   Sandip V. Chitale
  PDF4Eclipse   1.1.0   de.vonloesch.pdf4eclipse.feature.group  Boris von Loesch
  PyDev for Eclipse 4.3.0.201508182223  org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group  Fabio Zadrozny
  Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime   3.7.0.201505221634  org.eclipse.rse.feature.group   Eclipse TM Project
  StartExplorer  Feature    1.7.0   de.bastiankrol.startexplorer.feature.feature.group  Bastian Krol
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can view and export the list of Acrobat plug-ins along with their version as follows:

1. Open Acrobat and Click on Help
2. Click on “Generate System Report”
3. A dialog will be visible which has all the details to view and send a Report of available plugins along with their version #.

---

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]